# Why can't an iframe set its parent's location.hash?

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, security

I have a window containing an iframe, containing an iframe, like so:

```
+---------------+
|      Top      |
| +-----------+ |
| |   Middle  | |
| | +-------+ | |
| | | Inner | | |
| | +-------+ | |
| +-----------+ |
+---------------+
```

Top and Middle are on the same domain, but Inner is on a different domain.  I need Inner to communicate with Top.  The only way I know of to do this which is supported in IE7 (which I need to support) is to change the hash of the window's location.  However, I don't want the information to be flickering in the location bar, so I've introduced the Middle iframe.

I want Inner to change Middle's hash.  Middle will read its hash and inform Top, whom it has permission to speak to directly.

**However**, in Firefox 3, I've been unable to write to Middle's hash from Inner.  No error is raised, but the hash appears unchanged.  Writing to its `location.href` raises a permissions error.

Top can write to Middle's hash, however, and Middle can write to Inner's hash, and Top can write to Inner's hash, and Inner and Middle can both write to Top's hash, so the *only ordered pair* that doesn't work is the one I want!  (I've been working on this for a while.)

I've reproduced this in a minimal test case.  At first, I served all three pages from the same domain.  When I put Inner on a different domain, I get the problematic behavior.  When I put Middle on the second domain, everyone can write to everyone again.

Why can't Inner write to Middle's hash?

---

**Addendum**: Many people have suggested that this shouldn't be possible because of the same-origin policy.  This is exactly the policy I am trying to get around.  This exact case--setting (but not reading) another window's location--is supposed to be possible across domains.  I haven't found browser documentation to this effect, but I have found many articles and demos.  This is essentially the precursor to HTML 5's `postMessage()`.

Ref: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Comment: Sounds like it may be a security issue.

Comment: there's a dupe of this question on SO -- a bug in Bugzilla as well.

Comment: @Eric: Good to know. Do you have the links to those?  Post them as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parent frames can set children's iframe 'src' attribute (here with jquery) using:

```
$("#iframeWindow").attr('src', "http://<CHILD URL>/#hello");
```

Children iframes can set parent window's href (address bar content) using:

```
window.top.location.href = "http://<PARENT URL>/#hello"
```

and in the parent and/or child, you need to poll for changes,

```
var last = "";
setInterval(function() {
    if(last == window.location.href) return;
    last = window.location.href;

    //do stuff with 'window.location.hash'
}, 1000);
```

note, it would be nice if you could

```
window.top.location.href = window.top.location.href + "#hello"
```

but reading of location object (href and hash) is not allowed

tested on 3rd Nov 11, on chrome, ie6/7/9, firefox  3.6/4

edit1: can put a demo live if people would like

edit2: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14376395/html/xdomain.html :)

edit3: beware: if you're using this method, make sure you have control over all iframe'd pages otherwise nefarious 3rd party sites could potentially control yours using hash tags

edit4: better solution http://ternarylabs.com/2011/03/27/secure-cross-domain-iframe-communication/ currently being used by the Google JavaScript API

edit5: dropbox domain name changed to 'dl.dropboxusercontent.com'

Comment: Added (And I'm using dropbox/jsfiddle as the two domains)

Comment: To get around the problem where `window.top.location.href = window.top.location.href + "#hello"` is not allowed from the iframe, the parent window could pass in its own url (urlencoded of course) as part of the hash message it sends to the child.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to set the location.hash you must first get the location. The same origin policy forbids you from getting the location.

Comment: The same origin policy doesn't actually prevent you from getting the Location object, only its properties.  You should still be able to set them; see the link in the question's addendum.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this is a bug in Firefox, filed in Bugzilla, according to EricLaw.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the frames containing locations with the same origin? (eg. same protocol, same domain, same port).  If they're not it's a potential security vulnerability if one frame can modify the other -- google the same origin policy.  But without more details it's difficult to provide a better answer.

Comment: That's in the question: Top and Middle have the same origin; Inner has a different origin.  Setting the location is supposed to be a (safe, and I assume intentional) gap in the same-origin policy.  See the question's addendum.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the why bit for the hash, but have you seen John Resig's [work](http://ejohn.org/blog/postmessage-api-changes/) with `postMessage`? You're having trouble with FF3, FF3 happens to be one of the browsers that support `postMessage`, bingo :-)

Failing that, there's the [xssinterface](http://code.google.com/p/xssinterface/) library. Seems to be stable, but I haven't personally tried it.

Answer (score -1):

As Alex said it is a security issue. You can't access Top layer if Inner is on a different domain. This is made to avoid  [Cross-site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: See the question's addendum.  Writing to the location is supposed to be allowable, regardless of domains.